# SalesForce Bulk API: query relation on another custom object external id

Tags: bulk-api

I want to run a simple select query on a table, and include externalids of entities rather than salesforce ids...

This is my soql query normally works to select external id of User object :

```
Select Id, OwnerId, IsDeleted, Name, DateTime__c, External_ID__c, Notes__c, Source__c, Status__c, User__r.External_ID__c, FinishDateTime__c From Call__c
```

This query works in bulk api except `User__r.External_ID__c`, how can I select all Calls with external ids of users?

and this is xml structure

```
<complexType name="Call__c">
   <complexContent>
      <extension base="ens:sObject">
         <sequence>
            <element name="Account__c" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" type="tns:ID" />
            <element name="Account__r" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" type="ens:Account__c" />
            <element name="CallXContact__r" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" type="tns:QueryResult" />
            <element name="Contact__c" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" type="tns:ID" />
            <element name="Contact__r" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" type="ens:Contact__c" />
            <element name="CreatedBy" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" type="ens:User" />
            <element name="CreatedById" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" type="tns:ID" />
            <element name="CreatedDate" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" type="xsd:dateTime" />
            <element name="DateTime__c" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" type="xsd:dateTime" />
            <element name="External_ID__c" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" type="xsd:string" />
            <element name="FeedSubscriptionsForEntity" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" type="tns:QueryResult" />
            <element name="FinishDateTime__c" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" type="xsd:dateTime" />
            <element name="IsDeleted" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" type="xsd:boolean" />
            <element name="LastModifiedBy" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" type="ens:User" />
            <element name="LastModifiedById" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" type="tns:ID" />
            <element name="LastModifiedDate" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" type="xsd:dateTime" />
            <element name="Name" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" type="xsd:string" />
            <element name="Notes__c" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" type="xsd:string" />
            <element name="Owner" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" type="ens:Name" />
            <element name="OwnerId" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" type="tns:ID" />
            <element name="Sample_Products__r" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" type="tns:QueryResult" />
            <element name="Source__c" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" type="xsd:string" />
            <element name="Status__c" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" type="xsd:string" />
            <element name="SystemModstamp" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" type="xsd:dateTime" />
            <element name="User__c" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" type="tns:ID" />
            <element name="User__r" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" type="ens:User" />
         </sequence>
      </extension>
   </complexContent>
</complexType>
```

or what do you suggest to get external_id s of relational objects

Comment: Welcome. Can you rephrase so your answer is a little clearer?

Comment: sure tried my best

Comment: What error message are you getting? I assume your query above is just a typo? i.e. you have "External_ID_c" rather than the double underscored "External_ID__c". Assuming you are using the correct field name, it would be useful to know what error message you're getting.

Comment: no that was my typo while writing here: this is the simplified query i have just tried ->>> $soql =  "SELECT Id, Notes__c, Source__c, Status__c,User__r.External_ID__c FROM Call__c LIMIT 10";"

Comment: error is : PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'No result-list found in the results for Batch 751b0000000A3YBAA0' in /home/ec2-user/parser/bulklib/BulkApiClient.php:333
Stack trace:
#0 /home/ec2-user/parser/bulklib/samples/query_call.php(91): BulkApiClient->getBatchResultList(Object(SimpleXMLElement), Object(SimpleXMLElement))
#1 {main}
  thrown in /home/ec2-user/parser/bulklib/BulkApiClient.php on line 333

Comment: and this query works without User__r.External_ID__c... I know bulk api does not support this type of relational queries, but what is the solution for only external ids

Comment: Your User__c field might just be NULL on some records